# cython cannot insert into deque using iterators

Tags: c++, cython

I am wondering if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong:

```
from libcpp.deque cimport deque as cdeque

cdef cdeque[int] dq1, dq2

dq1.push_back(0); dq1.push_back(1)
dq2.push_back(2); dq2.push_back(3)
dq1.insert(dq1.begin(), dq2.begin(), dq2.end())
```

The above code gives me 2 similar errors at compile time: Cannot convert 'iterator' to Python object. Each error pointing at dq2.begin() and dq2.end().
When inserting only an int it seems to work but not with iterators.
Any ideas?

Comment: This bug has been fixed in Cython3.0: https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/4531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Cython versions prior to 3.0 (see this [PR](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/4531)).

On an prior version, we have the following options

**A: wrap `insert`, e.g.**

```
....
cdef extern from *:
    """
    template <typename T, typename It>
    void insert(T& dest, const It& begin, const It& end){
        dest.insert(dest.begin(), begin, begin)
    }
    """
    void insert[T, It](T& dest, const It& begin, const It& end)  
...
insert(dq1, dq2.begin(), dq2.end())
```

**B: changing/patching `libcpp/deque.pxd` in the local installation** from

```
void insert(iterator, input_iterator, input_iterator)
```

to correct

```
void insert[InputIt](iterator, InputIt, InputIt) except +
```

This however, will not help if pyx-files needs to be build somewhere else until Cython 3.0 isn't released/used.